# copy of a random variable X

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

If we have a random variable X,

What does mean by X′ denotes an independent copy of X.

by simple example.

thanks

Comment: Just means a random variable $Y$ with the same distribution as $X$, and independent from it.  If $X$ is the face shown by a fair die, $Y$ can be the face shown by a different fair die.

Comment: @lulu the same face

Comment: No ofc not always the same like $X$ otherwise they won't be independent… so if $X$ describes the throw of a die $Y$ describe the throw of ANOTHER INDEPENDENT die.

Comment: I don't understand.  The "face shown" by a die just means the face on top after you've tossed it.

Comment: If, say, you let $Y$ denote the bottom face of the same die that $X$ is the top face of, then it is true that $Y$ has the same distribution as $X$ but they are not independent.  Indeed $X+Y=7$.

Comment: we can say X and X' like two dies, sometimes they coincide in the same face (the same face is shown).... like this ?

Comment: I still don't understand.  If you have two dice, the faces are independent.  Of course they might sometimes be the same, or they might be different.  So what?

Answer (score 4):

It means that the distribution of $X$ is the same as the distribution of $X'$ and that $X$ and $X'$ are independent.

So, if $X$ is a continuous random variable with pdf $p_X$, then $X'$ is a continuous random variable with pdf $p_{X'} = p_X$, and for each pair of events $S_1$ and $S_2$, you have $$P(X \in S_1\land X' \in S_2) = P(X\in S_1)\cdot P(X'\in S_2)= P(X\in S_1)\cdot P(X\in S_2)$$

Comment: other thing 
why we use the copy of X for a such study. 
what is the important of X'

Comment: @Djamel Because, if $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, then $P(X<\frac12\land X>\frac 12) = 0$, while $P(X<\frac12\land X'>\frac12)=\frac14$.

Comment: @Djamel: it would be a good a idea to ask a follow-up question in a new post.

Comment: @Jack: what does it mean ''follow-up question''

Comment: @ 5xum : I didn't get yet 
P(X<\frac12\land X'>\frac12)=\frac14
how ?

Comment: @Djamel: Oh, that just mean to ask a new one. Since it would relate to this one, people call it a "follow-up" question.

Comment: @ 5xum :   I didn't get the second one ......

how ?

Comment: @Djamel Because $P(X<\frac12\land X'>\frac12) = P(X<\frac12)\cdot P(X'>\frac12)$...